# Can somone please tell me why does it print 1 instead of 2?

Tags: c, pointers

For some reason it prints 1 instead of 2 and i cant tell why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void f(int *p)
{
   *p++;

}
int main()
{
   int k=1;
   f(&k);
   printf("%d",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Essentially, `*p++` means `*(p++)`, not `(*p)++`

Answer (score 1):

Because you increment the pointer address and not it's value. Wrap it with parenthesis:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void f(int *p)
{
   (*p)++;

}
int main()
{
   int k=1;
   f(&k);
   printf("%d",k);
    return 0;
}
```